# Android project could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-plugin

`./gradlew build --info --debug --scan`

> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.

Below is the full log.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**Noted:**

I already add the AliYun maven repo to the project.

```
    maven {
        url "http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
```

In this way, I could download most of the dependency in jcenter and other maven repo which need to bypass the GFW.

I am using the network in Chinese wifi. I use ShadowsocksR and could visit https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom in Chrome.

Updated:

Every time I run the command line, it will show different but similar error, why this happen rather than show the same dependency which could not be resolved?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.1 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.1
      > Could not resolve com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.1.1/baseLibrary-3.1.1.jar'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.1.1/baseLibrary-3.1.1.jar'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Did you use a VPN?

Comment: Yes, I use ShadowsocksR as VPN. But I think I do not set the proxy for gradle command line.

Comment: Please use a VPN, not a proxy to tunnel the whole system

Comment: Could you share how to make it happen? And how to check if I set the proxy rightly?

Comment: Use OpenVpn or Cisco Anyconnect or other VPN protocols. There is no need to configure something in Android Studio

Comment: @Squti they are not free, right? Is there any other free ways? I already bought ShadowsocksR route.

Comment: You could find free OpenVpn accounts here https://www.vpngate.net